# Implementing MapKit iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, geofencing

I am implementing Mapkit in iOS application to make an application which shows posts to users based on his/her location like tinder do. I have tried an algorithm which calculates distance based on coordinates between user and posts. But it seems to be a very costly solution in terms of time, it has a very high complexity, i just wanted to ask is it the right way am doing or should i change my approach. Thank You.

Comment: post what you have done, to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can you [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) to find the distance between a origin & destination and update the posts aysnc. Hope it helps

*Note: You can also pass multiple origins in a single request.*